# E-Commerce low level design of Order class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, api-design

I am in middle of shopping website design. As of now I am stuck at one point and need a little feedback. Let us say I have an order class defined as follow:

```
class Order {

    Payment payment;
    Address ShippingAddress
    int orderId;
    List<Item> orderItem;
    double orderValue;  
    Buyer buyer;
    Date orderDate;
    NotificationService notificationService;
    Shipment shipment;
    
    List<OrderLog> orderLog;

    public OrderStatus placeOrder();
    public OrderStatus trackOrder();
    public void addOrderLogs();
    public PaymentInfo makePayment();
    public int createShipment();

}
```

Does it make sense to have `placeOrder()`, `makePayment()` etc.,API in order class? Or shall I make a separate `OrderManager` that helps to do all order related stuff and order will act as a pojo?

To me first one seems correct because the `placeOrder()`, `makePayment()` seems to me as behaviours of order and they should be in order class but on other class I think it is too much for an order class to do.Am i violating some SOLID principle by taking one approach over another? Since the OrderManager will also do same thing that we add in this class, do does it make sense to move it out?
`placeOrder()`, `makePayment()` etc, seems behavious of Order to me. Any thoughts?

On the extended note, how to be confident in deciding what will reside in class and what not?

Comment: Create a separate OrderManager class.  The Order class should only contain information about an order.  Placing an order combines Customer and Order information.  Taking a payment has nothing to do with the order, although the payment process needs to balance payments with orders.  Taking a payment combines Customer and Payment information.  As you gain experience, you'll get better in determining your system objects.  The more business experience you get, the better.

Comment: but i was reading some articles that Manager classes are bad and they introduction of manager class can be sign of bad architecture: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129537/can-manager-classes-be-a-sign-of-bad-architecture, although we use them in day to day life.But I started reading about SOLID and good design practices and then I started to get some doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I think:

1. If `Order` class is a data class, and you will use this class to store to database, I think you should move the functions:

```java
public OrderStatus placeOrder();
public OrderStatus trackOrder();
public void addOrderLogs();
public PaymentInfo makePayment();
public int createShipment();
```

from `Order` class to `OrderManager` class, because to implement every function (i.e `placeOrder`) maybe you need:

```java
private OrderValidator orderValidator;
private OrderService orderService;

public OrderStatus placeOrder() {
    if(orderValidator.validateOrder(this)) {
        orderService.saveOrder(this);
        return OrderStatus.OK;
    }
    return OrderStatus.NOK
}
```

but when you use a JPA (Entity) framework like [Hibernate](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-select-all), or [Spring JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example), they will load data from database and have no information of `orderValidator` or `orderService` to set to `Order` object. And you will need annotate `orderValidtor` and `orderService` with `@Transient` annotation, it makes you source code is complicated

2. If `Order` class is a [composite](https://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) class, maybe you can keep the functions in `Order` class and you don't need `OrderManager` class anymore, but you should combine your pattern with [Factory pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) and [Builder pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) like this:

```java
interface IOrder {
    Payment getPayment();
    Address getShippingAddress();
    //....
}

interface OrderValidator {
    boolean validateOrder(IOrder order);
}

interface OrderService {
    void saveOrder(IOrder order);
}

class OrderBuilder {
    private OrderValidator orderValidator;
    private OrderService orderService;
    private Payment payment;
    // other fields

    public OrderBuilder orderValidator(OrderValidator orderValidator) {
        this.orderValidator = orderValidator;
        return this;
    }

    public OrderBuilder orderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        return this;
    }
    public OrderBuilder payment(Payment payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
        return this;
    }

    public Order build() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderService(orderService);
        order.setOrderValidator(orderValidator);
        order.setPayment(payment);
        //set others
        return order;
    }
}

// Singleton
class OrderFactory {
    private OrderValidator orderValidator;
    private OrderService orderService;
    
    public OrderFactory(OrderValidator orderValidator, OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderValidator = orderValidator;
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    public OrderBuilder newOrderBuilder() {
        return new OrderBuilder()
                .orderValidator(orderValidator)
                .orderService(orderService);
    }
}

@Setter
@Getter
class Order implements IOrder

// usage
OrderFactory orderFactory = new OrderFactory(orderValidator, orderService);
Order order1 = orderFactory.newOrderBuilder()
        .payment(payment)
        // set others
        .build();
order1.placeOrder();
Order order2 = orderFactory.newOrderBuilder()
       .payment(payment)
       // set others
       .build();
order2.placeOrder();
```